# How can I generate this dynamic columns for table after getting the values from java controller in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, loops, html-table, thymeleaf

My table's all values come from the controller. After getting them, I showed them on the html table. But, I'm getting some problems while generating this dynamic table. what I want is this table:

**Expected table:**

[image]

whereas the information, title,values are coming from my database. But these are in the loop. My code is here:

```
<div>
<table class="dataTable">

  <th:block th:each="informations, iteration : ${data.listItems}">

      <th>Information</th>
      <th> Info <span th:text="${iteration.index+1}"></span></th>

      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td th:text="${informations.title}"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Class</td>
        <td th:text="${informations.class}"></td>
      </tr>

  </th:block>

</table>
</div>
```

which results in this table:

**Output table:**

[image]

repeating the row names, multiple times, which I don;t want. How can I modify this so it will generate my **expected** table shown on the above?

Answer (score 1):

I think< the esicion is something like that:

```
<div>
<table class="dataTable">

      <th>Information</th>
      
       <th:block th:each="informations, iteration : ${data.listItems}">
       <th>Info <span th:text="${iteration.index+1}"></span></th>
       </th:block>

      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
       <th:block th:each="informations, iteration : ${data.listItems}">
        <td th:text="${informations.title}"></td>
       </th:block>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Class</td>
       <th:block th:each="informations, iteration : ${data.listItems}">
        <td th:text="${informations.class}"></td>
       </th:block>
      </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I though that in this way, but as it was writing the same loop again and again, I might have posted only 3data, however I have almost 10 + data, that's why I wanted to check if there is another way

Comment: I understand it is not the best decision, but even after rereading thymeleaf docs i don't see beter one

Comment: Yep, this is the only way to do this (unless you want to transform your data beforehand to something you can loop over... like a List<List<String>>).